# how to calculate h-point

Tags: r, function, if-statement, text-mining, quanteda

I am trying to write a function to calculate h-point. the function is defined over a rank frequency data frame.
consider the following data.frame :

```
DATA <-data.frame(frequency=c(49,48,46,38,29,24,23,22,15,12,12,10,10,9,9), rank=c(seq(1, 15)))
```

and the formula for h-point is :

**if {there is an r = f(r), h-point = *r* }
else { h-point = f(i)j-f(j)i  /  j-i+f(i)-f(j) }**
where *f(i)* and *f(j)* are corresponding frequencies for ith and jth ranks and *i* and *j* are adjacent ranks that *i<f(i)* and *j>f(j).*

NOW, i have tried the following codes :

```
fr <-function(x){d <-DATA$frequency[x]
return(d)}

for (i in 1:length(DATA$rank)) {
j <- i+1
if (i==fr(i))
return(i)
else(i<fr(i) && j>fr(j)) {
s <-fr(i)*j-fr(j)*i/j-i+fr(i)-fr(j)
return(s)
}}
```

I also tried:

```
for (i in 1:length(DATA$rank)) {
    j <- i+1
    if (i==fr(i))
        return(i)
    if (i<fr(i) while(j>fr(j))) {
        s <-fr(i)*j-fr(j)*i/j-i+fr(i)-fr(j)
        return(s)
    }}
```

and neither of them works. for the *DATA* ,the desired result would be *i=11* and *j=12*, so:
h-point=12×12 - 10×11 / 12 - 11 + 12 - 10

can you please tell me what I`m doing wrong here?

Comment: @akrun just edited the question. a small data.frame is added. hope it makes a difference.

Comment: To fix your for loop you need to add a second if statement (`else` does not have the option of conditions) and close out the loop. What is the expected output for the DATA you provided?

Comment: @George thanks for the comment :). I added what is desired as a result. hope it makes a better sense now

Comment: Your first if statement isn't possible. i is set to run 1:15 or the length of Data$rank, and your function is reading the frequency in the xth row of your data frame, which are between 9 and 49. Your if statement is checking if 1==49, 2==48, 3==46, 4==38, 5==29, 6==24, 7==23, 8==22, 9==15, 10==12, 11==12, 12==10, 13==10, 14==9, or 15==9 and none of those are TRUE

Comment: Additional to @Tanner33 statement your are going to index out of bounds with j, on the last loop i == nrow(DATA) and j will be i+1.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
h_point <- function(data){
  x <- seq(nrow(data))
  f_x <- data[["frequency"]][x]
  h <- which(x == f_x)
  if(length(h)>1) h
  else{
    i <- which(x<f_x)
    j <- which(x>f_x)
    s <- which(outer(i,j,"-") == -1, TRUE)
    i <- i[s[,1]]
    j <- j[s[,2]]
    cat("i: ",i, "j: ", j,"\n")
    f_x[i]*j - f_x[j]*i / (i-j + f_x[i]-f_x[j])
  }
}

h_point(DATA) 
i:  11 j:  12 
[1] 34
```

Comment: thanks a million! only  small modifications are needed. length(h)>1 will never be true because it`s rank frequency data, so length(h)==1 is logical. and the last line needs a pair of parentheses to work : (f_x[i]*j - f_x[j]*i) / (j-i + f_x[i]-f_x[j]). also the denominator is (j-i+f_x(i)-f_x(j)),and not ( i-j + f_x[i]-f_x[j] )

Comment: @ sorry, should have states that `length(h)>=1`.This is a generalized code irespective of what you have. Even if you are using `f` as a function and not as the frequencies. Take a note that everything is vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out what you are trying to achieve. My loop will go through DATA and break at any point if `rank == frequency` for a given row. If might be more prudent to explicitly test this with `DATA$rank[i] == fr(i)` rather than relying on i, in case tied ranks etc.

The second if statement calculates h-point (`s`) for rows i and j if row i has rank that is lower than freq and row j has a rank that is higher.

Is this what you wanted?

```
DATA <-data.frame(frequency=c(49,48,46,38,29,24,23,22,15,12,12,10,10,9,9), rank=c(seq(1, 15)))
fr <-function(x){d <-DATA$frequency[x]
return(d)}

for(i in 1:nrow(DATA)){
  j <- i+1
  if (i==fr(i)){
    s <- list(ij=c(i=i,j=j), h=i)
    break
  }else if(i <fr(i) && j>fr(j)){
    s <-list(ij=c(i=i,j=j),h=fr(i)*j-fr(j)*i/j-i+fr(i)-fr(j))
}}
```

I am not sure the formula is correct, in your loop you had j-i but in explanation it was i-j. Not sure if the entire `i-j+fr(i)-fr(j)` is the denominator and similarly for the numerator. Simple fixes.